# jenkins: HTTP Request Plugin is returning Status 200 instead of content

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use jenkins httpRequest to get content of a webpage and I am weirdly getting only
Status 200 instead of actual code. following is the reproducible script and it's console log.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def response = httpRequest "https://news.yahoo.com/"
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build'){
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo "${response}"
                        echo response.getContent()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

console log:

```
HttpMethod: GET
URL: https://news.yahoo.com/
Sending request to url: https://news.yahoo.com/
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Success code from [100‥399]
....
Status: 200
....
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getContent() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the official documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/),
`response.content` contains the response content without headers.

So your code should be like this :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def response = httpRequest "https://news.yahoo.com/"
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build'){
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo "${response}"
                        echo response.content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```